# How can I search for records based on fields in a Waterline association?

Tags: sails.js, waterline

How can I do a search on a collection based on a field in an association table?

If we use the standard example of the User and the Pet from the Waterline docs (https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-docs/blob/master/associations.md), is it possible to, for example, search for all users that own a particular breed of pet (find me all the dog owners, for example)?

Is it as simple as something like:

```
User.find()
    .populateAll()
    .where({
        type: 'dog',
        breed: 'scotch collie'
    })
    .then(function (lassies) {
        // ...
    });
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently possible (as of Sails v0.10.x) to search by association.  For your purposes, the best solution would probably be to search for all pets of a certain breed, populate their owners, and concatenate the lists.  Something like:

```
Pet.find({type: 'dog', breed: 'scotch collie'})
   .populate('owners')
   .exec(function(err, dogs) {

       // Concatenate all the associated owners into one array using reduce,
       // then remove duplicates using uniq and the "id" attribute         
       var owners = _.uniq(_.reduce(dogs, function(memo, dog) {

           return memo.concat(dog.owners);              

       }, []), 'id');

});
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think it was possible. I'll probably end up creating a view to workaround it.

Comment: is this still the case? you can't search by association?